# How can I create an Android application (successfully exported) with JavaFX?

Tags: java, android, javafx-19

I am a new programmer, and I am learning JavaFX now. But I want to make Android apps too, and I searched for it online. I saw a few people was saying that we can create Android apps with JavaFX too. But there is no course or anything on how I can use JavaFX for Android app development. How can I create Android apps with JavaFX?

Thanks in Advance.

---

BTW I am using VS Code and have a JavaFX sdk installed. I did not found much results on the Internet. Please help me, I am a beginner, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Why dont you learn about android-studio? You would find many lessons and you have many opportunities in android development.

Comment: But Android Studio is very bulky, and I have a dell latitude e6420 laptop that have 4gb ram, and it cannot handle a bulky and huge software like this, that's why I want to make android apps with low resources.

Comment: fair enough, the only video I found that maybe help you is this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4VdX_FtAg8.

Maybe in the future make an upgrade to yourself and try Android-studio. There are many lessons and really you can do many things on your own. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, sir, for helping, I will try to do better in future if I make money with my apps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to build JavaFX apps for Android (and also iOS) you need to use the tooling provided by Gluon. Extensive documentation can be found here: https://docs.gluonhq.com/
There are also some tutorials, e.g., this one https://foojay.io/today/creating-mobile-apps-with-javafx---part-1/